# Can I pull CAT6 cable via old RJ11 panels?

Tags: wiring, ethernet

I have spotted multiple RJ11 ports in the home I am moving into soon. They are spread across the first and second floors of the house. **Is it possible to use that existing wiring to pull through CAT6 cable to use for an RJ45 port and a patch panel where the phone line originally terminated?** If so, are there any dangers? Is there something I should be actively looking for? This is an older home (early 1900's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems you are likely to run into.

1. Pulling new wiring with existing is hit and miss, sometimes you can do it but sometimes wires are clipped/stapled in places you can't access, sometimes the cable routes have too many turns or obstructions to pull and sometimes the wires are just directly buried in plaster.
2. Old phone wiring was often daisy chained whereas Ethernet wiring needs an individual run from each point to the network switch.

The bottom line is you may be able to reduce the damage to decor by pulling wiring in some places using the existing wiring but it is very likely you will end up having to do some damage in the process of getting the new wiring in.

Pulling through the wall between an outlet and a space under the floor or above the ceiling may or may not be possible, pulling through a run between multiple rooms without any intermediate pull points is highly unlikely to be possible.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I'm confused at how these homes managed to snake all this wire through the house in the first place, especially one that is this old, and to multiple floors that are diagonal to the termination!

Comment: @Kahn  Very likely some or all of the original wiring was put in place during construction, i.e., before the walls were buttoned up.

Comment: Depending on just how old the house is it may have been put in during construction, if not it may have been put in place and then the house redecorated covering up the damage that was done to put it in.

Comment: Life also gets much easier if the house has an attic and/or crawlspace that cna be used to route wiring.

Comment: Ah, OK. Yes, the place has a huge attic, so that could explain some things. Well, if all else fails I'm sure I can just use a weather-graded CAT6 cable on the outside of the house. Not ideal, though. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: It can also be worth checking what actual cabling is used. It's not super common but best case scenario is that it was star wired and done in something like cat5e and can just be reterminated. This can also be the case for new work as it's easier just to carry data cable and use it for phone so new work can be suitable for data, but may be daisy chained.

Comment: It's worth checking, but unless the phone wiring was re-done in the last decade or so it seems unlikely.